# How can I introduce the URI I need

Tags: google-sheets-api, gravity-forms-plugin

I can't get the client token code from google spreadsheet addon gravity forms. I have got the Client Id, the secret code and I have filled the domain, etc. But i dont know how to solve this issue.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, https://findoit.app/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/125591414320-20nvdkbr8cepaf436densffj569492bf.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=125591414320

Comment: Can you describe a bit more in detail what you are trying to do? Are you using normal user OAuth authentication or a server account?

Comment: I think I am using normal OAuth. I am setting up google spreadsheet add-on and when I try to generate the token client code I get this issue. I have requested credentials, verified the domain, etc, following all steps

Answer (score 0):

### How to set-up the redirection URI

- Go to your [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com)
- Choose a project
- Go on APIs & Services -> Credentials
- +Credentials
- Create OAuth client ID
- Choose `Web Application`
- Specify `Authorized redirect URIs`
- If required: add the URI to the authorized domains list before submitting
- Create credentials

Comment: I have done exactly what you are telling but I get an error: The redirect URI in the request, https://findoit.app/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/125591414320-nmq0htfmbff76elenh8a6nr6692gr8eh.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=125591414320

Comment: Are you sure that the domain has been added to the authorized domains list before submitting?

Comment: I have added https://findoit.app and https://findoit.app/wp-admin.  are these domains ok?

Comment: Go on APIs & Services ->Domain verification. You will see: You need to verify domain ownership to allow webhook notifications to be sent to your external domains. Google verifies that the user owns each of the listed domains via Search Console. So the domain needs to be yours. See also [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en)